# how to use a variable (read from a file) for url in curl using batch script for windows?

Tags: batch-file, curl, window

curl -I -H "Cache-control: no-cache" -w 'a'
)
www.google.com
url: www.youtube.com
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%u in (file.txt) do curl "%%u"
```